# Bluetooth BLE Device disconnects as soon as connected?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth

I've been writing an app using Swift that connects to a bluetooth BLE device. For some reason, the app doesn't always connect to the device. In this case it will connect but gets disconnected straight away. This only happens maybe 1 in 10 times it connects, but definitely interferes with the reliability of the app. 
I'm using `CoreBluetooth` to connect to the BLE device. Attempting connection again usually always gets it to reconnect, and other apps that communicate with this device works correctly every time, so I'm confident that it is not a problem with the peripheral.

I'd just like to know if there is anyone out there who has had a similar issue or if there is a particular reason why this may be happening?

EDIT: Here's the code for the willSelectRow of my table. This is where I get the peripheral to connect.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        centralManager.stopScan()
        connectingPeripheral.append(discoveredDeviceArrayInfo[indexPath.row])
        connectPeripheralNow(connectingPeripheral[0])

        return indexPath
}
```

This is where I get it to connect, at this point I select the row which sets the CBPeripheral details of the device to connect to.

connectPeripheralNow looks like this:

```
    func connectPeripheralNow(peripheral: CBPeripheral!){
    self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

didConnectPeripheral and didDiscoverServices looks like this

```
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager,didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral)
{

    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: "FFE5")])
    print("SUCCESS: Connected to " + peripheral.name!)
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?)
{
    if let servicePeripherals = peripheral.services as [CBService]!
    {
        for servicePeripheral in servicePeripherals
        {
            print("INFORMATION: Service discovered " + String(stringInterpolationSegment: servicePeripheral.UUID))
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: servicePeripheral)

        }

    }
}
```

Just for the info, I do get a 'SUCCESS: Connected to xxx' message appear which shows that it is connecting. If you need more code, let me know!

Comment: Can you add code of delegate methods?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added some code to the edit section. If you need a little more code, let me know!

Comment: Make sure you store the peripheral you are connecting to in a strong variable - it is in your `connectingPeripheral` array, but if it is ever removed from this array then it will be released and the connection will fail.  I suggest you create another property/iVar, say `connectedPeripheral` and store it in that

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation, I'll do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are mentioning is more of an expected behaviour. BTLE is designed to consume very little amount of energy so it drops the connection as soon as possible. If you do not need a permanent connection then follow **Discover --> Connect --> Read/write --> Setup timer --> When timer fires Connect.**

If you need a permanent connection, you should subscribe for characteristic which transmits real time data like heart rate application. You would need to implement `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` method. Read [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the post! This is a really useful piece of information here, I'll have a read over and try this implementation method since I need a permanent connection to my peripheral. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. All the best. Do let me know if that fixes your issue. Would help me guiding others as well :).