# Immediate Bluetooth device disconnection only when the Apple watch is connected to an iphone

Tags: ios, bluetooth, apple-watch

I experience a very strange issue.
My IOS application installed on an iPhone connects to a bluetooth device. I can discover/connect/get characteristics. I can also send and get data.
We have discovered an issue when an apple watch is paired to the iPhone. The bluetooth device connects, discovers characteristics, but then immediately (no delay) disconnects via the didDisconnectPeripheral callback for the reason : "The connection has timed out unexpectedly". If I unpair the apple watch, everything comes back to normal.

I have tried to automatically reconnects the bluetooth device, but got no luck.
I tried the Apple watch with other bluetooth device, and it successfully connects.
I tried bluetooth devices together and it also works.
Then I tried to deactivate some apple watch features and put it in sleep mode (This seems to close the bluetooth connection), didn't work either.
I tried some answers on stackoverflow like : [Bluetooth BLE Device disconnects as soon as connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693815/bluetooth-ble-device-disconnects-as-soon-as-connected)

I have no clue about the bluetooth device hardware I use :

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x15453b1d0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x154576cb0, UUID = Model Number String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x15453b850, UUID = Serial Number String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x154572690, UUID = Hardware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x15456c8b0, UUID = Firmware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x15456edc0, UUID = Software Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x15456fda0, UUID = System ID, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1545824f0, UUID = IEEE Regulatory Certification, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

The issue occurs on iPhone 6S, with IOS 9.2 apple watch 2.0.
I don't know how to face that problem.
Does anyone had this kind of issue ?

Thanks,